# Add addresses content to multiple google map markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add the location address to the marker content. I'm getting the address by the coordinates and this is working, but on the map will always display only the last address.

Here is my example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 400px;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
</div>
<script>

    function initMap() {
        var locations = [
            [-33.890542, 151.274856],
            [-33.923036, 151.259052],
        ];

        var styleArray = [
            {
                featureType: 'all',
                stylers: [
                    {saturation: -80}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'road.arterial',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [
                    {hue: '#00ffee'},
                    {saturation: 50}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'poi.business',
                elementType: 'labels',
                stylers: [
                    {visibility: 'on'}
                ]
            }
        ];

        var image = {
            url: 'map_icon.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(30, 45),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 35),
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25), // default map position
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: styleArray,
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var marker, i;
        var mapContent = '';

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);

            geocoder.geocode({
                        latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                    },
                    function (responses) {
                        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                            mapContent = responses[0].formatted_address;
                        }
                    }
            );

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(mapContent);

                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

        }
    }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap&sensor=true"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read some docs about [Using closures in event listeners](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure):

```
geocoder.geocode({
  latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
  },
  function (responses) {
      if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
          mapContent = responses[0].formatted_address;
          var  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: responses[0].geometry.location,
              map: map,
              icon: image,
          });       
          addContent(map, marker, mapContent, infowindow);
       }
  }
);



function addContent(map, marker, mapContent, infowindow ){
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(mapContent);

                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker));
}
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/2029/